# Checkboxcolumn в datagrid c#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagrid

Привет. Добавил колонку чекбоксов через свойство датагрида на скрине, а чекбоксы не выделяются и никак не реагируют на клик.
Что не так, подскажите?
или может лучше/правильнее сделать программно? подскажите как?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел вот такой код и он работает. т.е. все нажимается.
Это правильный код?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell ch1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
    ch1 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0];

    if (ch1.Value == null)
        ch1.Value=false;
    switch (ch1.Value.ToString())
    {
        case "True":
            ch1.Value = false;
            break;
        case "False":
            ch1.Value = true;
            break;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(ch1.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: можно еще свич заменить скажем этим: `ch1.Value = !(bool)ch1.Value`

Comment: найдите по типу все чекбоксы и проставляйте им свойства